# How to combine two XPath queries in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to check an XML document for two rules via XPath evaluate.

The rules are:

- /root/path1/text()='TABLE1'
- /root/path2/text()='TABLE2'

My code looks like:

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(myDocument);
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager xpathNsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);    
xpathNsMgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
var result = (bool)navigator.Evaluate("((/root/path1/text()='TABLE1') and (/root/path2/text()='TABLE2'))", xpathNsMgr);
```

If I check both XPath via evaluate for their own, then everything works. But if I check them combined as shown in the code above, I get the following error:

```
xsltcontext is needed for this query because of an unknown function
```

Why isn't it possible to combine both XPath and evaluate them together? I thought "and", "or" etc. are valid operators since XPath 1.0...

Comment: I thought and or are used for evaluating the attributes of each [element](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)? It's possible the /root needs to be outside the outer brackets.

Comment: @lloyd is this XPath 1.0 specific? Because the above shown expression works flawlessly at: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: Are you sure you get that error for the posted XPath expression? I don't see any unknown function in there. Your comment to Tomalak's answer shows the use of a function `exists` which is indeed not defined in XPath 1.

Comment: Oh...exists() is indeed a XPath version, but XPath 2.0... https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp So, I have to search for another library to evaluate those expressions, because they are given via an external system/partner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Tomalak and and @Martin Honnen, my conditions are not fully supported by XPath 1.0. Functions like exists() are part of XPath 2.0.

Since .NET 4.5 (which I have to use) doesn't support XPath 2.0, I used the following Nuget package to solve my problem: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2/

Just replace

```
navigator.Evaluate(...
```

with

```
navigator.XPath2Evaluate(...
```

And the expression can be evaluated.

Comment: I doubt that Microsoft's `System.Xml.XPath`, whether in any .NET framework version or as a NuGet package for .NET Core use, does really support any XPath 2 functions or expressions, it is simply the type system and the API that was designed to be usable with XQuery 1 or XPath 2 but the implementation was never carried on further, or at least not released any further. So Microsoft gives you with XPathNavigator and XPathItem a foundation to build XPath 2 or XQuery 1 on, but if you want to use functions or expressions from these languages then you have to turn to third party implementations.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I edited my answer. (Last sentence.) Do the changes reflect, what you added in your comment?

Comment: No, I don't think there is any support for XPath 2.0 syntax like sequence expressions, `for .. in` etc. in Microsoft's implementation. The statement about "The System.Xml.XPath namespace contains the classes that define a cursor model for navigating and editing XML information items as instances of the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model" is in the documentation of `System.Xml.XPath` since .NET 2.0 I think, as that is what put Microsoft in there to document the architecture of that namespace. Any support for more was abandoned in favor of LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1):

.NET XPathNavigator supports XPath 1.0 only.

You can model your check easily by turning the condition into a predicate (square brackets) and see if the resulting node-set is empty or not.

```
var result = navigator.Evaluate("/*[path1 = 'TABLE1' and path2 = 'TABLE2']", xpathNsMgr);
```

Here `/*` selects the document element. Write `/root` instead if the actual name of the document element is important.

Comment: Ok, this works for the given example. But what if I want to combine `(/root/path1/text()='TABLE1') and (exists(/root/path3))` ? I think I will evaluate them one by one and then do the logical checks/combination afterwards...

Comment: `exists()`? There is no such function. Selecting a node checks its existence. `/*[path1 = 'TABLE1' and path3]`.